# Adding image to mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this.
I am having trouble saving my image to the database.
The input from the comment which is a string and the input from the rating will go in but the image will not save to my database.
trying to create a site that will take images from someone who is rating their haircut. The code i have come up with is below.

```
<form method="post" id = "bodyContainer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<img src="" name="image" id="image"/>
<br/>
<input style="float:right;"type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser" onchange="return ValidateFileUpload()" />

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateFileUpload() {
        var fuData = document.getElementById('fileChooser');
        var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;

    //To check if user upload any file
        if (FileUploadPath == '') {
            alert("Please upload an image");

        }   else {
                var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

                //The file uploaded is an image
                if (Extension == "gif" || Extension == "png" || Extension == "bmp" || Extension == "jpeg" || Extension == "jpg") {

                // To Display
                    if (fuData.files && fuData.files[0]) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function(e) {
                            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        }

                        reader.readAsDataURL(fuData.files[0]);
                    }

                } 

                //The file upload is NOT an image
                else {
                    alert("Photo only allows file types of GIF, PNG, JPG, JPEG and BMP. ");

                }
            }
    }
</SCRIPT>   

<textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea><br/>
<input type="range" name="rating" min="1" max="5" id="rating"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/><br/>
```

The main issue i believe arises from the php that adds the code to the database below.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['comment']) {

            $comment = addslashes($_POST['comment']);
            $rating = $_POST['rating'];

            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image) ;

            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","DJP"); 
            $query = "INSERT INTO reviews (comment, image) VALUES ('$comment', '$image')";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);    
            if ($result) {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("image uploaded");</script>';
            }else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("image not uploaded");</script>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of your `name` attribute. Look at this statement here,

```
<input style="float:right;"type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser" onchange="return ValidateFileUpload()" />
                                                ^ see here
```

It should be,

```
<input style="float:right;" type="file" name="image" id="fileChooser" onchange="return ValidateFileUpload()" />
```

Comment: ok i understand i just tried that. I must have been under the assumption it would take it from the image. You were very helpful.

Comment: @MichaelVickers Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: @devpro `<img>` tag has nothing to do with `<input>` tag. The problem is, the `name` attribute in `<input>` tag is wrong.

Comment: thats fine, actually there r two solution for this, one u suggested and second one i suggested :) good work

Comment: @devpro Thanks buddy. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your input type file name is `dataFile` not image. so you can get file information as

```
$image = addslashes($_FILES['dataFile']['tmp_name']);
$name = addslashes($_FILES['dataFile']['name']);
$image = file_get_contents($image);
```

Note that you have defined `name='image'` in `<img>` tag. you can't get this in `$_FILES`.

Comment: This could be the alternative approach. +10 from me. :-)